# Localhost takes too long to respond. Connection timeout

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I am a beginner programmer and I regularly use xampp as a localhost server with which I make small projects for learning purposes.  Now suddenly, I am not able to connect to localhost  or phpmyadmin whatever I try.

I have trued changing the port multiple times,  I tried reinstalling xampp,  I changed localhost to `127.0.0.1`, I tried flushing dns, I tried to change from xampp to wamp and I even tried removing uac but even after all this I still get a message localhost took too long to respond and I get a connection timeout error.

Please help me fix the issue.

Comment: Is Apache running? Check the status in the XAMPP control panel and look in the Apache logs.

Comment: You wrote that you've changed the port, where did you edit that and why? Unless you have a reason to change from the defaults, you should stick to the default port settings.

Comment: I have checked with apache in xampp and the logs.  It is running and i have changed the port within httpd.conf after trying to find solutions.

Comment: Make sure you're trying to use that modified port when you're loading the page in your web browser. Double-check the port that's defined in `httpd.conf`, restart Apache just to be safe, and then load it up in the browser (such as http://localhost:99999 or whatever port you've defined).

Comment: Yes i have tried using the port while loading the page and i have tried restarting apache many times before posting this issue and still there has been no issues.

Comment: I have tried to using both wamp and xampp but i have had no results.  Now currently i am trying my luck with wamp.  Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Can you paste the line where you changed the port in the configuration file?